# Quick function for Carrying Subsets in R

Tags: r, loops, subset

I want to calculate how many collaborations for each author in my dataset, my data is like [image: this]

The first column is authors and the second column in article id. So each article was written by a sole author or several authors.

The codes I am using is basically a loop,

```
degree1 <- rep(NA, length(Name))

for(i in 1:length(Name)){
    temp <- subset(mydata, mydata$data == Name[i])  
    temp <- subset(mydata, mydata[, 2] %in% temp$artid)
    CC <- unique(temp$data)
    degree1[i] <- length(CC) - 1
    print(i)
}
```

where Name is the author vector by using

```
Name <- unique(mydata$data)
```

But this kind of loop is very slow since I have more than 1000000 authors, are there any quick way to do so?

Comment: Can you please give a small sample data set and the expected output? "..calculate how many collaborations for each author.." Does that mean, "For each author, how many other authors has this one worked with?"

Comment: Yes exactly....

Answer (score 1):

```
library(data.table)

# make dataset
n = 20
set.seed(123)
x = data.table(
  author = LETTERS[1:n],
  artid = sample.int(n, replace = T)
)
x = x[order(artid)]

# collaborations
x[, n := uniqueN(author), by = artid]
```

Comment: uniqueN(author) counts unique cases, whereas .N counts all cases.

Answer (score 0):

I read through the comments and I think I got what you are trying to arrive at
I created a dummy example which mimics your situation.

```
library(dplyr)
art_id <- c(11, 11, 11, 10, 10)
author <- c("Ajay","Vijay","Shyam",
            "Ajay","Tarun")
uniq_art <- unique(art_id) # get unique article id
```

So in this case Ajay has collaborated with three authors ('Shyam',
'Vijay' and 'Tarun').

Shyam and Vijay each have collaborated with two authors
Tarun has only collaborated with one author.
My solution to your problem is not very elegant. 
Hope someone can provide a more elegant solution.

```
# Make the data frame
publish <- data.frame(art_id, author)

# subset for a particular aritcle ID 
# group by author and get the number of authors each author 
# has worked with

b <- publish %>% filter(art_id == uniq_art[1]) 
c <- b %>% group_by(author) %>% summarise(ans = dim(b)[1]-1)

# Repeat the process and join results to above data frame
# for the remaining article IDs

for(i in 2:length(uniq_art)) {
  b <- publish %>% filter(art_id == uniq_art[i]) 
  d <- b %>% group_by(author) %>% summarise(ans = dim(b)[1]-1)
  c <- full_join(c, d, by = "author")
}    

# get the number of columns
nc <- ncol(c)

# sample output after running loop in my dummy case

# A tibble: 4 x 3
  author ans.x ans.y
  <fctr> <dbl> <dbl>
 1   Ajay     2     1
 2  Shyam     2    NA
 3  Vijay     2    NA
 4  Tarun    NA     1

# Add all numeric values in each row to get total collaborated authors    
total_collab <- rowSums(c[,2:nc], na.rm = T)
final_ans <- c %>% mutate(total = total_collab)
final_ans

# A tibble: 4 x 4
  author ans.x ans.y total
  <fctr> <dbl> <dbl> <dbl>
1   Ajay     2     1     3
2  Shyam     2    NA     2
3  Vijay     2    NA     2
4  Tarun    NA     1     1
```

Hope this helps.

Comment: `count(...)` is handy; it's the same as `group_by(...) %>% summarise(n = n()`